# Need to sort a list of data from firebase using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a firebase database set up to have the user enter data, which creates a parent object in the database. Each parent has child data, mainly a name of the object and a date.

I was wondering if there was a way to sort the data and then display it on a web page? The code I have to pull the data and make a table on a web page using it is as follows:

```
firebaseRef.on("child_added", snap => {
var name = snap.child("name").val();
var date= snap.child("date").val();
var id = snap.key;
var childAuthor = snap.child("author").val();
var thisAuthor = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;


if (childAuthor == thisAuthor) {
var html = '<tr id ="'+id+'"><td>'+ name + '</td><td>' + date+ '</td><td><button onclick = "removeClick(this)" id ="'+id+'">Remove</button></td></tr>'; 

$(html).appendTo('#table_body');    
}
```

});

This will pull the data into a nice little table for me. But I would like to sort the data to display the closest date first, and the latest date last (This would mean that June 1st would be written first into the table, then June 5th next etc.) Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `firebaseRef.orderByChild("date").on(...`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! I looked up the link you posted and it worked just fine. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.